# ApexCharts - Como adicionar uma quebra de linha em uma label em um RadialBar

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou precisando inserir um texto longo no centro de um radial bar, de forma que se ajuste adequadamente, por exemplo com uma quebra de linha. O texto que quero alterar fica no local do exemplo colocado como "text here..."

Está sendo usado angular com a biblioteca apexchart instalada em seu ambiente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já procurei na documentação formas de alterar a label, mas não consegui achar uma que se aplica-se para um radial bar.
[Link da biblioteca](https://apexcharts.com/docs/installation/)

[Link do projeto executando online no stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubuwuk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

O trecho de código onde é informada a label é o seguinte:

```
 public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  hexChartColor = '#3076B5';
  hexTrackColor = '#DAE7FD';
  percentValue = 70;
  textChart = `text here text here text here text`;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      colors: [this.hexChartColor],
      series: [this.percentValue],
      chart: {
        height: 400,
        width: '100%',
        type: 'radialBar',
        background: '#f1f1f1'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        radialBar: {
          inverseOrder: false,
          startAngle: 0,
          endAngle: 360,
          offsetX: 0, // Move chart sides
          offsetY: 0, // Move chart top, bottom
          hollow: {
            margin: 5,
            size: '60%',
            background: 'transparent',
            position: 'front'
          },
          track: {
            show: true,
            startAngle: undefined,
            endAngle: undefined,
            background: this.hexTrackColor,
            strokeWidth: '97%',
            opacity: 1,
            margin: 5
          },
          dataLabels: {
            show: true,
            name: {
              show: true,
              fontSize: '14px',
              fontFamily: undefined,
              fontWeight: 600,
              color: '#3076B5',
              offsetY: 20
            },
            value: {
              show: true,
              fontSize: '44px',
              fontFamily: undefined,
              fontWeight: 600,
              color: '#3076B5',
              offsetY: -20,
              formatter: function(val) {
                return val + '%';
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      labels: ['text here text here text here text text here']
    };
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chart">
  <apx-chart 
    [series]="chartOptions.series" 
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart" 
    [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
    [labels]="chartOptions.labels" 
    [colors]="chartOptions.colors">
  </apx-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Alguém deu downvote e nem explicou o por quê, acho que não tem nada de absurdo na pergunta ...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar dentro de um array

```
labels: ['text here', 'text here', 'text here', 'text', 'text here'],
```

Isso funciona nos gráficos de linhas e barra, deve funcionar para você.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já tentei essa solução antes, mas ele não faz a quebra de linha amigo. Atualmente meu design fez uma outra abordagem pra esse texto, nós diminuimos o texto pra ficar melhor ao usuário. Mas vou deixar a pergunta aberta para ajudar alguém da comunidade.